# OpenCV directshow camera access results in black image unless the camera has been opened previously from other software

Tags: opencv, directshow

An analog framegrabber's image can be read via OpenCV only after the demo-application has opened the grabber, otherwise a black image results.
The following debug code

```
qDebug() << "Brightness" << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS);
qDebug() << "Contrast  " << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST);
qDebug() << "Saturation" << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION);
qDebug() << "Hue       " << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_HUE);
qDebug() << "Gain      " << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN);
qDebug() << "Exposure  " << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE);
qDebug() << "Width     " << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
qDebug() << "Height    " << cap->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

outputs

```
Brightness 5000
Contrast   5000
Saturation 4000
Hue        5000
Gain       -8.58993e+08
Exposure   -1
Width      720
Height     576
```

Of course these settings seem defective, but they are the same when opening the device successfully after it has been accessed by the grabber's demo application.

I suppose this is a driver issue where certain device settings are required that OpenCV cannot access, including invalid standard settings (gain, exposure). What lower-level methods could be used to find out about / write those settings?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that camera actually did not load yet and OpenCV already tries to take the image.
For me querying couple of more frames usually helps, like this:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
if ( capture ) {
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    for (int i = 0; i < `0; i++)
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    }
    cvSaveImage("mypic.jpg",frame);
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
}
```